# 401.2 Error with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting a 401.2 error when I move my web app from our test server to our production server. The app uses forms authentication and it runs perfectly on the test server.Anonymous access is enabled on both servers. What else could be causing the 401.2 error? (401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.). Any assistance would be very welcome!

Thanks,
Caroline

Answer (score -4):

First make sure in your web.config everything is ok.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043/) you can find Microsoft Support article for 401.2 Error.

Comment: Downvoted for the vague advice. What should Caroline be checking in the web.config? Specifics are crucial.